# How do I return a template(thymeleaf) in spring boot and resolve it to a particular endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

**Short:** I want to use Thymeleaf template index.html but have the url point to thanks.html.

**In depth:** I am trying to have a form submission take my user to a page http://localhost:8080/thanks.html.  I dont want the action of the form to be thanks.html for a few different reasons but I have greatly simplified the logic below.  When all of the validation of the form are passed, I want to pass in a variable to indicate which layout to use.  I have that working by using a model variable called contentPage.  The problem is that if i have "return "thanks.html";" in the indexSubmit Method I get an error from thymeleaf saying template not found.  If I change that to "return "index.html"; everything works but the url is http://localhost:8080/ instead of http://localhost:8080/thanks.html.

```java
@PostMapping("/")
public String indexSubmit(Model model) {        
    model.asMap().clear();
    model.addAttribute("contentPage","layout/thanks.html");
    return "thanks.html";   
}

@GetMapping("/thanks.html")
public String thanks(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("contentPage","layout/thanks.html");
    return "index.html";
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on my own:

```java
return "redirect:thanks.html";
```